# Continuously ping an IP address in background

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

My Windows Form application is using the **.NET framework 3.5**.

It needs to continuously ping an IP address (like `ping IpAddress -t`) and outputs the results in labels.

I am unable to do this using ping.sendAsync function. I do not have access to Threading.Task since I'm working in 3.5. **Is there any alternative to this functionality?**

My goal is to develop an application such as [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/481080/Continuous-asynchronous-Ping-using-TAP-and-IProgre), using .NET 3.5.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms144961(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

In your `PingCompleted` event handler initiate a new `SendAsync()`.

Comment: I want to develop below application in Frame work 3.5. Here i have a probelm, i did not found Threading.Task namespace in Framework 3.5. see this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/481080/Continuous-asynchronous-Ping-using-TAP-and-IProgre

Comment: You don't need Task. Use `SendAsync()` and `PingCompleted` like suggested in my answer.